# Javascript - Swap input element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, swap

saw something on xe.com where they swap currency on the form. I need something for my site also. Basically this is not a question, solve the problem and sharing here:

**HTML**

```
<form target="">
<input name="input1" id="firstinput" value="input #1">
<input name="input2" id="secondinput" value="input 2">
</form>
<a class="swap">Swap</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.swap").click(function(){
        var axix = document.getElementById("firstinput").value;
        var byiy = document.getElementById("secondinput").value;
        document.getElementById('secondinput').value = axix;
        document.getElementById('firstinput').value = byiy;
     });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Vse/

any better way to do it?
share with us. :)

Comment: The best thing you can do is to replace `document.getElementById` with `$('#...')` as you are using jQuery.

Comment: @AliBZ, can you elaborate little bit more?

Comment: @j08691, any other simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Shorter (not necessarily "better"):

```
$("a.swap").click(function () {
    $('#pickup').val([$('#destination').val(), $('#destination').val($('#pickup').val())][0])
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z5Vse/1/)**

IMO "better" would mean clean, clear, and concise.

```
$("a.swap").click(function () {
    var temp = $('#pickup').val();
    $('#pickup').val($('#destination').val())
    $('#destination').val(temp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQUERY and one less variable used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.swap").click(function(){
        var axix = $("#pickup").val();        
        $('#pickup').val($("#destination").val());        
        $('#destination').val(axix);        
     });
});
```